# Regex in python not matching what grep does

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, osx-yosemite

I have the following string:

```
string1; 1.8w/v PEG_8000; string2; ;;
```

I want to get the `; 1.8w/v PEG_8000;` part. I tried the following:

```
a =re.search(';[^.;]+PEG[^.;]+;','string1; 1.8w/v PEG_8000; string2; ;;'
```

which returns `a = None`.

What am I missing?

(OS X Yosemite, Python `2.7`)

**Edit:** I previously said the following, which I discovered not to be true. I forgot that I edited the string before I tried this.

> The funny thing is, if I do `grep -E --color ';[^.;]+PEG[^.;]+;'
>   file`, where `file` contains the string, it can highlight it.

**Edit 2:** I have a huge file with such strings, where the keyword `PEG` does not necessarily appear in the second field. That is why I don't use `split(';')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the dot from the first character class. Because there is a dot exists between the semicolon and the sub-string `PEG` which causes the regex to fail. Note that dot present inside a character class matches only a literal dot.

```
>>> re.search(r';[^;]+PEG[^.;]+;','string1; 1.8w/v PEG_8000; string2; ;;').group()
'; 1.8w/v PEG_8000;'
```

Comment: What does that change? Also what changes when you add  the `r`?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate you need to remove the dot from character class that's all.And it's always better to use raw string notation.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit confused, though. Isn't it the case that `.` means any character and `\.` actually means dot?

Comment: dot inside a character class matches a literal dot.

Answer (score 2):

A negated character class matches everything **except** those specified characters. Therefore the literal `.` is causing the problem here. You can modify your regular expression as follows:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'string1; 1.8w/v PEG_8000; string2; ;;'
>>> re.search(';[^;]+PEG[^;]+;', s).group()
'; 1.8w/v PEG_8000;'
```

Answer (score 1):

A way without `re`:

```
>>> s='string1; 1.8w/v PEG_8000; string2; ;;'
>>> ';'+s.split(';')[1]+';'
'; 1.8w/v PEG_8000;'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not tell you that the string is a part of a huge file, where the field with the keyword `PEG` is not always the second column.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate, You should add that requirement to the question.